# Alternatives to the default django template system

Tags: python, django, django-templates

What are the most used alternatives to the default templating system of django?

Has anybody of you tried any?

EDIT:
What about performance?

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: i have no reason to do that, i'm just asking for curiosity, would like to hear other experiences.

Comment: Can you expand on your question to indicate what your current opinions are on the django template system? Do you not like it? Does it lack something? Would you prefer to generate all your html markup directly from python code?

Comment: "asking for curiosity" doesn't really improve a poor question.  If you could provide some reason, or direction or rationale or purpose, we could provide a specific answer.  If you're just curious then toss a coin, they can all be made to work.

Comment: well i read that jinja according to some people is better so I wanted to know if there are other alternatives and if anybody has tried them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jinja2 is very much like Django templates: http://splike.com/wiki/Convert_Django_Templates_to_Jinja2

Mako is very much NOT like Django.

Try these two and see what approach you like best.

Comment: do you have any info about the performance? Do these different system perform differently?

Comment: @nemesisdesign Mako is very fast in my experience.   http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/faq/ claims that both Jinja2 and Mako are 10 to 20 times faster than Django templates.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe jinja2: http://lethain.com/replacing-django-s-template-language-with-jinja2/

Why do you want to replace it? It is very powerful and has so much built in support. I would think you would want to replace it if you already had a specific template system in mind.

Answer (score 1):

[Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/) is the most popular replacement I know of. The biggest difference is that it allows you to put significantly more logic and code into your templates: Django’s templating system is deliberately restrictive in this regard.

I have used Jinja2 and have to say I personally prefer Django’s template system, simply because it encourages a cleaner style where as much processing as possible is done in the view code, making refactoring and testing easier.

As for performance, there is a [section in the Jinja2 FAQ](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/faq/#how-fast-is-it) which claims Jinja2 and Mako are roughly equivalent, and both about 20 times faster than Django’s template renderer, but also points out that such benchmarks are all but meaningless.

Comment: I tend to agree with @dhwthompson, the Django template engine is restrictive on purpose. Even though Django compiles these templates it still isn't the fastest process and adds unneeded complexity to the system.

Answer (score 1):

[Coffin](https://github.com/coffin/coffin) project contributors are trying to build a complete drop-in replacement for Django Template. Coffin api loads Django Filters and tags for you, so you can enjoy Jinja templating and use existing Filtes and Tag Libs written for Django.
Coffin project is actively maintained. You can read more reference here:

1. justcramer.com/2009/09/14/using-jinja2-with-django/
2. matthowell.com/blog/2011/03/02/integrating-jinja2-and-django/

Comment: Coffin seems to have disappeared from GitHub, maybe it's dead entirely now?

Comment: It is indeed dead. The [Coffin Pypi listing](https://pypi.org/project/Coffin/) changed in April 2015 to read: "This used to be a full-featured standalone adapter. With Django adding support for other template backends, it’s approach didn’t make sense anymore. Please use `django_jinja` instead..."

Answer (score 0):

I don't use templates at all, preferring a pure python OO approach.

To be able to do this I code a small but useful library in Python, that let me generates any mark-up code.

I could say that the experience is somehow similar to the one you can have with a tool such as QT... obviously, my tool is way smaller than a vast tool like QT, there are some similarities, especially in the use of classes and the Composite pattern.

I think many people will dislike my approach. However, if you want to take a look, here is the link to the code:

[Pytml framework](https://bitbucket.org/daniele-niero/pytml)

Comment: Both these links are broken. Do you have new links?

Answer (score 0):

https://pypi.org/project/yawrap/
Templateles, pure pythonic html generator. It's fast, has no dependencies, runs on python 2.7, 3.x and pypy.
Outputs ideally indented html code with zero overhead (indents for free).
No need to use tags or filters from django, because you already have absolutelly everything in python.